# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't read file "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45522\sv_ttk\sv.tcl": no such file or directory

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, ttk, thonny

I have used [Sun Valley Ttk Theme](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme) for my project (.py). It works on IDE (Thonny) but doesn't work when I converted the .py file to .exe.

I got this error for the line: `sv_ttk.set_theme("light")`:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't read file "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45522\sv_ttk\sv.tcl": no such file or directory.
```

Obviously this directory doesn't exist but why should it? What should I do?

Theme folder, .py and .exe are in the same directory.

Besides I used

```
-add-data
```

to add theme folders as additional while converting to .exe.

Comment: What did you pass to `--add-data` exactly?

Comment: @JRiggles Sun-Valley-ttk-theme-main and all of its subfolders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `sv_ttk` module into the executable by using `--collect-data` option of `PyInstaller`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --collect-data sv_ttk project.py
```

Assume `project.py` is the main python script.

Comment: Make sure the `sv_ttk` not only installed in the specific venv, but also your global python environment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and this is my solution. I think it's more like a tricks

1. Find your Python Directory where you save it in your computer

my case: C:\Users\PC-Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

2. Go to Folder `tcl` -> `tk8.6`
   and put your custom .tcl file here (Ex: sprites_light.tcl)
3. Execute your programs by `pyinstaller Main.exe`
4. When Done, Go to your Program Folder. There is a new folder created.
   Go `dist` -> `<your-exe-file-name>` -> `tk` And find your tcl file . If it's there then you've made it
5. Finally, because it will need some *.png files to run well, so you will also copy the folder containing the png to the above folder (inside tk folder)

Goodluck, I hope it helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and I thought share it here for all who needs it:

To convert Python to Windows

```
import os
import sys

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS # after running the pyinstaller, if still looking
        # for temp folder then use sys._MEIPASS2 and if needed \\ instead of / for
        # all the path directories
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Replace the "img/file_names" with resource_path("img/file_names")

in the Terminal type:
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed  --icon=your_image.ico Your_File.py

or
in windows CMD type:
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=your_image.ico Your_File.py

The executable file will be available in a new folder called "dist".

now copy all the dependent folders into the "dist" folder

run the .exe and if all fine then zip the folder to share.

Delete Build and Dist folder along with any .spec files.

Replace the resource_path("img/file_names") back to "img/file_names"

Use "inno setup" software to create a proper setup file, use this link towards the end of the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3tSLatmGvU

If file not found error:
Use MEIPASS instead of MEIPASS2 or vise versa and then \ instead of / if needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).